# MSBuild Set Property to Influence Restore/Build of Project Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a shared library that needs to be used by both .Net 5 and .Net Framework 4.8 projects. Due to other complexities in the build process, it is impossible to simply have multiple `TargetFrameworks` defined in the shared library, so I want to use an `MSBuild` property to dynamically set if the shared library should target .Net 5 or .Net Framework 4.8. This approach works when I pass the flag property via MSBuild (`/p:Net48=True`) but does not when I define the MSBuild property directly in csproj file.

Below is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

Project A:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\C\C.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Project B:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Net48>True</Net48>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\C\C.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Project C (Shared Library):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework Condition="'$(Net48)' == ''">net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFramework Condition="'$(Net48)' != ''">net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Running `dotnet build B.csproj /p:Net48=True` builds the project while `dotnet build B.csproj` fails. Shouldn't the property definition `<Net48>True</Net48>` have the same impact as setting the flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't the property definition True have the same impact as setting the flag?

No - properties set in Project A do not propagate to projects referenced by Project A, so when you execute `dotnet build B.csproj` the property `Net48` is undefined in Project C.
However, properties set on the command line apply globally to all projects (and take precedence over property values set statically in a project file) which is why setting it on the command line works.

You don't actually need any special conditional logic in this case, as SDK-style projects support building for multiple target frameworks.

Simply change your Project C to the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#targetframeworks --> 
        <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="DisplayTargetInfo" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Message Importance="high" Text="$(MSBuildProjectName) TargetFramework = $(TargetFramework)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```